# Cross compile openssl on bare metal

Tags: openssl, arm, posix, cross-compiling, dirent.h

I'm trying to cross compile openssl using the corresponding gcc (arm-none-eabi-5_4-2016q2) for a cortex m3 machine. The machine should have the ability to do TCP request and we'd like to do HTTPS at the end of the day.

During the cross compiling, at the make step, I have encountered the error saying some struct that should be defined in dirent.h aren't, and as I checked more closely, it turns out that this compiler has only an otherwise empty dirent.h other than error printing.

Obviously the machine will be running without dirent.h. So my question is, can I still compile this openssl for the machine? Could it be an option that I write the corresponding things myself in case the header is necessary? But it's just about directories, how related is it to SSL anyways?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options:

- wolfSSL Embedded SSL for Bare Metal https://www.wolfssl.com/ Project
- Goals - BearSSL https://www.bearssl.org

See: [Comparison of TLS implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TLS_implementations)